# I am trying to make a default popover from bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding some new functionality for my page and I'm looking to use bootstrap tooltips, the thing is I want a custom tooltip using html but my code isnt working. Here is my JavaScript:

```
$("#container").popover({
    html: true,
    title: function() {
        return ("<div color='black'>" + title + "</div>");
    },
    trigger: 'hover',
    content: function() {
        return ("<div color='black'>" + text + "</div>");
    }
});
```

`Title` and `text` are variables with some value.

Comment: so do you want to make tooltip or popover? :)

Comment: sorry, a popover, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is an example of something that I have done/ used
here is the css:

```
 <style>
    .popover-title{
        background: #428bca;
        color:  #ffffff;
    }
</style>
```

Here is the html:

```
<a rel="popover" id="test" data-color="yellow" title="My Title" data-placement="top"
                                data-content="Say something!" >
```

This would be the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$('#test').popover('show');},5000);
    setTimeout(function(){$('#test').popover('hide');},15000);
    $('body').click(function(e) {
        $('#test').popover('hide');
    });
    $('#test2').hover(function(){
                if ($("#popoverTrigger").next('div.popover:visible').length){
                    $('#test').popover('hide');
               }else{
                     timer1 = setTimeout(function(){$('#test').popover('show');},900);
                     timer2 = setTimeout(function(){$('#test').popover('hide');},4800);
                    }
               },
               function(){clearTimeout(timer1); clearTimeout(timer2); $('#test').popover('hide');
               });
});
```

What is going on here is a popover at a location in one of my divs. And then it after 5 seconds it comes up. After 15 seconds it goes away. If a click was registered on the page it also goes away. Also there is a hover method

Comment: thanks, I am already showing a popover, the thing is it doesnt display the information the way I want

Comment: Well... how do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: I want it to have black colored font, for some reason its always white, and if I open the popover, I cant read anything because of that. I just want to change my font color, been trying different things, cant do it.

Comment: This is a css issue then I'll edit my post. Also don't be afraid to hit the check mark under the up/down error next to the post if it works.

Comment: Good :D I am happy to help